# Appcelerator controller appear/disapear methods

Tags: appcelerator

I'm pretty new to Appcelerator and was wondering what the listeners for the view life cycle are?

For example, if I wanted to detect the iOS viewWillAppear and viewDidDisappear methods, or Androids OnResume, OnPause methods, then how would I do this the "Appcelerator" way?

I've searched around on the web, but only able to find in the Titanium documentation info about the application state such as Active, Suspended, ect. I need a controller, or window, specific listener to react to.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Titanium abstracts those events for you - so you don't have to worry about writing them for iOS/Android each.

Check out the [Titanium.App documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App) (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App). You can see what events are available at the app level (of course, each Titanium components has it's own events - but those are at app level).

If I understand your question, the relevant events for you are [paused](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-paused) and [resumed](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-resumed) - when the app goes in the background and then back to foreground.

Comment: As stated in my question above I've already looked into the application level events. As per my question I am looking for controller level, or screen level, events. For example, the viewDidAppear method is a controller specific event as opposed to applicationDidEnterForeground which is an application level event. Therefore, paused and resumed are NOT what I am looking for. I need controller level events. When can I detect when a screen is shown and dismissed and not the application.

Comment: Are you looking for the window.focus or window.onPostLayout events? That would fire and window.close would fire. Does that help?

Comment: @Ray you close to being correct. the Window.focus event is what I was looking for to detect when the screen comes into the view, and then the Window.blur event is the one for detecting when the view leaves the screen. I appreciate all of your help, and if you want to post this as an answer then I'll up vote it and mark it as the approved answer. Unfortunately, the answer above was giving me app level events, so it's not the appropriate answer.

Comment: @miken.mkndev also have a look at open even of the window - it behaves differently than focus event.

Comment: @developer82 Yes, that's like the viewDidLoad method in iOS or the OnCreate method in Android. Thanks!

Comment: It's important to note that Controllers and Windows are independent objects. If you are looking for open/close/resume/pause events you will have to look into the Window object. Controllers are just javascript modules that let you write xml/tss.